# Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' on AUTO_INCREMENT field

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with a `PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` column. I started running an event that runs `ALTER TABLE update_log REORGANIZE PARTITION`. Suddenly my clients (which `INSERT`) started getting errors `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '146255393' for key 'PRIMARY'`.

I noticed that the duplicate entry was the same as the `AUTO_INCREMENT=…` value returned by `SHOW CREATE TABLE update_log;`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `update_log` (
  `update_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `org_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `inventory_id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `item_url` text NOT NULL,
  `item_update_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`update_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=146255393 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (update_id)
(PARTITION initial VALUES LESS THAN (1000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `1000000-1999999` VALUES LESS THAN (2000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `2000000-2999999` VALUES LESS THAN (3000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `3000000-3999999` VALUES LESS THAN (4000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `4000000-4999999` VALUES LESS THAN (5000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `5000000-5999999` VALUES LESS THAN (6000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `6000000-6999999` VALUES LESS THAN (7000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `7000000-7999999` VALUES LESS THAN (8000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `8000000-8999999` VALUES LESS THAN (9000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `9000000-9999999` VALUES LESS THAN (10000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `10000000-10999999` VALUES LESS THAN (11000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `11000000-11999999` VALUES LESS THAN (12000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `12000000-12999999` VALUES LESS THAN (13000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `13000000-13999999` VALUES LESS THAN (14000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `14000000-14999999` VALUES LESS THAN (15000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `15000000-15999999` VALUES LESS THAN (16000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `16000000-16999999` VALUES LESS THAN (17000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `17000000-17999999` VALUES LESS THAN (18000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `18000000-18999999` VALUES LESS THAN (19000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `19000000-19999999` VALUES LESS THAN (20000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `20000000-20999999` VALUES LESS THAN (21000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `21000000-21999999` VALUES LESS THAN (22000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `22000000-22999999` VALUES LESS THAN (23000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `23000000-23999999` VALUES LESS THAN (24000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `24000000-24999999` VALUES LESS THAN (25000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `25000000-25999999` VALUES LESS THAN (26000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `26000000-26999999` VALUES LESS THAN (27000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `27000000-27999999` VALUES LESS THAN (28000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `28000000-28999999` VALUES LESS THAN (29000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `29000000-29999999` VALUES LESS THAN (30000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `30000000-30999999` VALUES LESS THAN (31000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `31000000-31999999` VALUES LESS THAN (32000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION future VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */;
```

So I manually altered the AUTO_INCREMENT value to be one greater than the maximum value in the table: `ALTER TABLE update_log AUTO_INCREMENT=146262544;`

Then the same error happened again (`java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '146255393' for key 'PRIMARY'`), and I again tried to increase AUTO_INCREMENT by hand to a much higher value: `ALTER TABLE update_log AUTO_INCREMENT=146300000;` Then the error happened again (`java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '146311957' for key 'PRIMARY'`).

Edit (to answer question from @RaymondNijland): All the inserting clients get the same error at the same position. The insertions to the table are made using the slick library which compile into:

```
insert into `update_log` (`org_id`,`inventory_id`,`item_url`,`item_update_count`)
select s37.`org_id`, s38.`inventory_id`, s38.`item_url`, s38.`item_update_count`
from `org` s37, `inventory_version` s38
where (s37.`org_code` = 'myorg') and ((s38.`org_id` = s37.`org_id`) and (s38.`inventory_id` = ?))
```

By the way, also I noticed in `SHOW TABLE STATUS\G` that `Rows` does not match `COUNT(*)`:

```
mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS\G
…
*************************** 6. row ***************************
           Name: update_log
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Dynamic
           Rows: 0
 Avg_row_length: 0
    Data_length: 1425408
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 0
      Data_free: 158334976
 Auto_increment: 146311958
    Create_time: 2019-08-23 22:01:31
    Update_time: 2019-08-23 22:01:31
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8mb4_general_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: partitioned
        Comment: 
…
mysql> SELECT MAX(update_id), COUNT(*) FROM update_log\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
MAX(update_id): 146312275
      COUNT(*): 255167
```

What’s going on? Am I doomed to manually increment my auto_increment primary key forever?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with all these partitions?

Comment: @duskwuff The purpose of the partitions is to delete all old rows after several days using `DROP PARTITION`.

Comment: how do the insert qeuries look and Java code look like? Clients...also does every client get this error to "rule out"  race condition **maybe** or does one insert on the first client work.... Also did you check if the ID which you got the error also really existed in the table  to confirm as there is something very fishy going on here..

Comment: @yonran Well, they aren't working! Your autoincrement ID is 5 times higher than the last partition.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have added more to the main text to answer your question. @duskwuff You’re right, currently all items are in the `future` partition; the event is running the stored procedure once per minute until it creates a partition that includes the `MAX(update_id)`.

Comment: Suggestion: Have you tried copying the table into a new table, then swap them with rename? With less than 300,000 rows, this should not take a horribly long time and may reset things to "normal".

Comment: Suggestion: upon re-reading comments above, try using "DELETE FROM `update_log` WHERE `update_id` < {arbitrary value}" instead of mucking about with partitions? I can't say which method would be faster, but a) this way is more common and thus more easily understood by more people and b) it avoids any problems or bugs inherent in the MySQL Partitions system, which I expect doesn't get nearly as much testing or proving.

Comment: Thanks @UncaAlby for your suggestions. I created a new table `LIKE` the old one and swapped them using `RENAME`, but the error occurred again, twice. But now I have tried creating enough partitions to cover all existing data so that there are no rows in `future` when I run `ALTER TABLE update_log REORGANIZE PARTITION future`, and I haven’t been able to reproduce the error. Seems like I shouldn’t reorganize a non-empty partition if there is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column and there are concurrent `INSERT`s.